# How to I fix warning C4047?

Tags: c, ctype

I got a warning C4047: 'return': 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *' from my compiler.
I'm new to coding and don't understand how to fix this problem.

My code is:

```
char upperToLower(char word[])
{

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }

    return word;
}
```

Can anyone help me with the code?

the array number for char word[] is 25, so char word[25].

Answer (score 1):

Word is the pointer to char not char. Your function returns char not pointer to char.

It should be:

```
char *upperToLower(char word[])
```

And I personally prefer

```
char *upperToLower(char *word)
```

as it is less confusing for the beginner C programmers.

If the `word` is the C string (null char (or another words zero ) terminated char array) it should look like this:

```
char *upperToLower(char *word)
{
    char *wrk = word;
    while(*wrk)
    {
        *wrk = tolower((unsigned char)*wrk);
        wrk++;
    }

    return word;
}
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did not assume anything. The keyword here is **`if`**. `if the word is the C string .....`  . Where  did you find the **assumption**

Comment: `tolower(*wrk)` is improper; it should be `tolower((unsigned char) *wrk)`. And OP had a nice `for` loop which did not need to be expanded into a `while` with separate initialization and update statements. If it had to be changed to process a C string rather than a fixed 25 bytes, the only change that was needed was to change the test from `i < 25` to `word[i]`. There was no need to rewrite it using pointers OP may not yet have learned. If it is rewritten, the C `for` is designed to work nicely in this situation: `for (char *work = word; *work; work++) *work = tolower((unsigned char) *work);`.